# Creating a list and indexing

Tags: php

Given a two list. Create a third list by picking an odd-index element from the first list and even index elements from the second.
For Example:

```
listOne = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21]
listTwo = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28]
```

Expected Output:

Printing Final third list
`[6, 12, 18, 4, 12, 20, 28]`

Comment: Have you made any effort in solving this yourself yet?  If it's an interview question, they are trying to understand what you can do and not what we can do.

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, it will be helpful for you.

```
<?php 

$listOne = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21];

$listTwo = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28];

$NlistOne=[];
$NlistTwo=[];

//odd-index positions from list one [6, 12, 18]
foreach ($listOne as $key => $value) {
    if($key%2==1){
        array_push($NlistOne, $value);
    }
}


//even-index positions from list two [4, 12, 20, 28]
foreach ($listTwo as $key => $value) {
    if($key%2==0){
        array_push($NlistTwo, $value);
    }
}

//Printing Final third list [6, 12, 18, 4, 12, 20, 28]
print_r(array_merge($NlistOne,$NlistTwo));

?>
```

Output will be:

```
Array ( [0] => 6 [1] => 12 [2] => 18 [3] => 4 [4] => 12 [5] => 20 [6] => 28 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//init result array

//loop over listOne, using for($i=1;$i<sizeof($listOne);$i=$i+2)
//and add to result for each iteration, $resultArr[] = $listOne[$i]

//do the same with listTwo, but for($i=*0*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge both of arrays and then pick all odd elements

```php
$listOne = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21];
$listTwo = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28];
$result = [];

foreach ( array_merge($listOne, $listTwo) as $value ){
    if ( $key % 2 ) {
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
```

If array length isn't fixed, say it could contain not 7 elements, then you need to check it before merging to make it have odd number of elements

```php
$listOne = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 777];
$listTwo = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28];
$result = [];
if ( count($listOne) % 2 !== 1 ) {
    $listOne[] = 0;
}
foreach( array_merge($listOne, $listTwo) as $value ){
    if ( $key % 2 ) {
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to loop over whole array array_filter will  do this for you, Constant ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY will check each key for odd or for even

```
<?php
$a1 = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21];
$a2 = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28];

function odd($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is odd
    return $var & 1;
}

function even($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is even
    return !($var & 1);
}

$result= (array_merge(array_filter($a1, 'odd', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY),array_filter($a2, 'even', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY)));
```

output you will get

```
Array ( 
[0] => 6 
[1] => 12 
[2] => 18 
[3] => 4 
[4] => 12 
[5] => 20 
[6] => 28 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over first one and take only values of odds indices, and loop again through second one and take evens indices.

```php
$listOne = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21];
$listTwo = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28];
$res = [];
for ($i=0; $i < count($listOne); $i++) { 
    if($i & 1) // $i is odd.
        $res[] = $listOne[$i];
}
for ($j=0; $j < count($listTwo); $j++) { 
     if(n % 2 === 0) // $j is even.
        $res[] = $listTwo[$j];
}
```

**Result*:*

```php
echo "List One :".json_encode($listOne)."<br>";
echo "List Two :".json_encode($listTwo)."<br>";
echo "Lists Merged:".json_encode($res);
```

**Output**:*

```
/*
List One :[3,6,9,12,15,18,21]
List Two :[4,8,12,16,20,24,28]
Lists Merged:[6,12,18,4,12,20,28]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over arrays:

- take *odds* in array starting with index **One** and increment it by *two*.
- take *evens* in array by starting with index **Zero** and increment it by *two*.

```php
$listOne = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21]; $listTwo = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28];
$res = [];
for ($i=1; $i < count($listOne); $i+=2) {
    $res[] = $listOne[$i];
}
for ($j=0; $j < count($listTwo); $j+=2) {
    $res[] = $listTwo[$j];
}
print(json_encode($res)); // [6,12,18,4,12,20,28]
```